# catching ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

I am making a project for my school and I have handle all exceptions, but I am just not able to handle the ArrayOutOfBoundsException. 
so I searched for a solution on stackoverflow and it says to use IndexOutOfBoundsException (link to the solution : [why is it not catching the arrays out of bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458449/why-is-it-not-catching-the-arrays-out-of-bound))
 but it didnt work. please help?
here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(fruit[i] + fruitprice[i]);
}
System.out.println("\n" + "please enter the number marked for the icecream you want to buy");
do {
    x = 0;
    try {
        icenum1 = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine()) - 1;
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        System.out.println("please enter in numbers and not in words.... please try again");
        x = 1;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("please enter a number out of the given numbers and not any other number");
        x = 1;
    }
} while (x != 0);
System.out.print("\u000c");
System.out.println("your choice is " + fruit[icenum1]);
```

Comment: You need to use an array type of object or a collection to get this exception thrown. Where are you using one in your try bloc?

Comment: @YassinHajaj i am making a project which is currently 512 lines long, and i am really new to this so...

Comment: Yes that is no problem. We've all been there, my question was not sarcastic but was just a way for you to find the right path to your problem resolution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these lines into your try bloc if it still respects your code's logic.

```
System.out.print("\u000c");
System.out.println("your choice is " + fruit[icenum1]);
```

If an `IndexOutOfBoundException` is thrown, it will be from the second line because it'll try to access an index that does not exist in your current array.